# Unable to implement Vue.Js to bind data into html table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this mock eCommerce app which is able to show products. AddToCart is functional which is can be seen in `console.log(joined);`. But `joined` is not bind to html table via Vue.

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];
let htmlProducts = '';

products.forEach(function(product) {
  htmlProducts = htmlProducts + `<div style="border: 1px solid red">\
                <h2>${product.productName}</h2>
                <p>RM ${product.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                <p><button class=AddToCart data-id="${product.id}">Add to Cart</button></p>\
                </div>`;
})

document.getElementById("productRow").innerHTML = htmlProducts;

function createUUID() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
      v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

function cart(productId, quantity) {
  this.id = createUUID();
  this.productId = parseInt(productId);
  this.quantity = quantity;
}

const addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart");

var carts = [];
var joined = [];

[...addToCart].forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {

    const foundIndex = carts.findIndex(
      prod => prod.productId == element.dataset.id
    )

    if (foundIndex === -1) {
      carts.push(new cart(element.dataset.id, 1));
    } else {
      carts[foundIndex].quantity = carts[foundIndex].quantity + 1;
    }

    joined = carts.map(item => {
      let {
        unitprice,
        ...rest
      } = products.find(p => p.id === item.productId);
      debugger
      return {
        'cartId': item.id,
        'unitprice': unitprice,
        'quantity': item.quantity,
        'total': unitprice * item.quantity,
        ...rest
      };
    });

    console.log(joined);
  });

});

debugger
var cartTable = new Vue({
  el: '#cartTable',
  data: {
    rows: joined
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="productRow"></div>

<table id="cartTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in rows">
            <td>{{row.id}}</td>
            <td>{{row.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.unitprice}}</td>
            <td>{{row.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{row.total}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: why'd you using vue.js and manipulate the DOM at the same time?

Comment: I am trying out to use Vue.js to auto refresh the cart table (Observe pattern). Otherwise, when I delete or update the cart quantity, I have to print the cart again everywhere

Comment: I cannot understand why you have so many operations on DOM when using Vue? You should change you mindset when using Vue, it is different from the traditional ones like jQuery, or something directly manipulating DOM. My suggestion is that you'd better to read the Vue docs to change you way of coding, then come back to see these problems.

Comment: Echoing what @fengxh said. This whole setup makes no sense. All of this logic should be part of the Vue app. All of that DOM manipulation, event listeners, and I see html generation.. is what Vue is MEANT to do. For instance: you should be adding the elements to `this.rows` within the Vue app. You definitely need to restructure all of this